# how to get last plsql pass to oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Is it possible to get the last plsql which was parsed to oracle database from an application via sqlplus as sysdba?

And how?

Thanks

Comment: hmm what purpose would this serve?

Comment: can you explain me?please

Comment: the problem is I dont have the source code for the server. I am only building a client and I do have the priveledge as the oracle sysdba. At the moment, there is some db error from proxy method which is parsed, i know which pl sql procedure is causing error but no idea what parameters was pass to the procedure by the server which caused it to fail.

Answer (score 2):

I use this SQL to find recent queries and their bind variables. I'm not certain you can find the 'last' sql submitted - what happens if five clients submit different SQL at identical times? And I'm not certain this captures every query, and I don't know how to correlate with a SYSDBA user. If you respond I will do a little more research.

```
select  
LAST_LOAD_TIME,
PARSING_USER_ID,
sql_id,  
t.sql_text SQL_TEXT,  
b.name BIND_NAME,  
b.value_string BIND_STRING
from  
v$sql t  
join 
v$sql_bind_capture b  
using (sql_id)
where  b.value_string is not null  
and t.module= 'SQLPLUS.exe'
order by LAST_LOAD_TIME DESC, BIND_NAME
```